# TypeORM: Define relation in migration

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

Hi I'm reading TypeORM docs, and trying to implement relations like showed here
Im trying to have History model that relates to every User, so that each user has multiple history

Im reading this & using that example:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md

But after try to implement it I get column userId on History model does not exist ??

Does anyone know what could be  the problem ?

Im assuming I should add relation in migration file for my Model but I do not see any of that in documentation ?

Comment: Have you tried to let TypeORM [generate](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#generating-migrations) the migration file for you? That should add the needed columns and foreign key constraints to the migration.

Comment: Yes I checked found solution by looking at the docs thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The queryRunner has a method called `createForeignKey`. In a migration file where you create a table it could look like this:

```js
export class ExampleMigration implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.createTable(
      new Table({
        name: 'stuff',
        columns: [
          {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'uuid',
            isPrimary: true
          },
          {
            name: 'userId',
            type: 'uuid'
          }
        ]
      })
    );

    await queryRunner.createForeignKey(
      'stuff',
      new TableForeignKey({
        columnNames: ['userId'],
        referencedTableName: 'users',
        referencedColumnNames: ['id']
      })
    );
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.dropTable('userSessions');
  }
}
```